# Silverstripe v2.4.5 & UserForms

Tags: php, debugging, silverstripe

Firstly a bit of background - I work for a digital agency, and we inherited our client's site from another agency. It's an old site which is running a very old, out-of-date and unsupported version of Silverstripe - v2.4.5 - but our client is resistant, despite our strong recommendations, to upgrading due to the time and cost that it would involve, but they want us to add forms to the site which involves installing the userforms module and it's fallen to me to try and do that. My knowledge of PHP is limited and debugging it is a virtual unknown to me.

I've managed to find the version of the Userforms module (v0.3) that is supposed to be compatible with the version of Silverstripe is being used and I have followed the installation instructions and have rebuilt the database but, unlike previous attempts where I've made some updates, it does not give me the "Build successful" message and it outputs the following result which I've saved for easy viewing here:

http://stg.fourleaf.co.uk/misc/downslaw/forms/silverstripe-rebuild-result.html

As far as I can tell, it doesn't output any errors as such, but it doesn't build successfully either and the forms module does not install.

Does anyone have any insights as to what may be wrong or how I can go about finding out what where things are going wrong? As I mentioned, my knowledge of PHP is minimal so I'm a little out of my depth.

Comment: What version of php is the site running on? 5.3 should work but 5.4 produces that error according to http://www.zenserve.eu/php-programming/silverstripe-2-4-running-on-php5-4/

Comment: I’m assuming your client requires the ability to add dynamic forms thus why you need to use userforms? If not then just make a static form(s).

Comment: @GavinBruce Ah, I think it might be 5.4. I'll check further. Thanks for the heads up!